# How many days until X-Y-Z date?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to build a count-down widget.

Given a certain date, whats the easiest way in PHP to determine how many days until that date?

Comment: One-liner: `echo (new DateTime('2019-12-17'))->diff(new DateTime())->days;`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```php
       <?php
         $cdate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2009);
         $today = time();
         $difference = $cdate - $today;
         if ($difference < 0) { $difference = 0; }
         echo floor($difference/60/60/24)." days remaining";
       ?>
```

Comment: This really depends on your definition "days until".  For example this snippet tells me new years eve is 34 days away, and wolfram alpha, google, siri, and just about every other site i search is telling me 35 days.  FWIW

Comment: @AlBeebe then just add +1. What's so hard about that?

Comment: I think that's because the snippet counts the days till Dec 31 00:00, not till what most people think of new years eve (Dec 31 23:59 or Jan 01 00:00)

Comment: Please make note that in mktime(): The is_dst parameter is now [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Comment: Where's the love for `DateTime`? I know this is an old answer but using `mktime` feels a bit archaic at this point when `DateTime` is much more reliable these days than any existing PHP date function.

Answer (score 31):

Expanding on schnaader's answer, here is a one-liner function that takes a date string as a parameter but only returns the number of days:

```
<?php
function days_until($date){
    return (isset($date)) ? floor((strtotime($date) - time())/60/60/24) : FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot and works a treat to get the number of days from a date.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for one that gives negative, this helped a lot!

Comment: For some reason yesterday is -2..... what happened?

Comment: A date in the past might give you a negative number.

Answer (score 9):

Don't treat dates as integers. Use your database, which has good support for dealing with calendars/time.

```
select datediff("2009-11-12", now())
```

Comment: ummmm, that's not [tag:php]

Answer (score 9):

PHP 5.3 has introduced the DateTime class that implements a 'diff' function.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 7):

Days minutes and seconds format:

```
// current time
$today = new DateTime(format_date(time(), 'custom', 'd M Y H:i:s'));
// date to which we want to compare (A Drupal field in my case).
$appt  = new DateTime(format_date($yourdate_is_timestamp, 'custom', 'd M Y H:i:s' ));

// Months
$months_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)-> m;
// days
$days_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)-> days;
// hours
$hours_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)-> h;
// minutes
$minutes_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)-> i;
// seconds
$seconds_until_appt = $appt->diff($today)-> s;

echo 'days until: ' . $days_until_appt;
echo 'hours until: ' . $hours_until_appt;
echo 'minutes until: ' . $minutes_until_appt;
echo 'seconds until: ' . $seconds_until_appt;
```

Comment: `DateTime` class FTW

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php `->days` (for example) is not a valid class method. Can you please modify your code to use `->format('d')`, `->format('m')`, etc. so it's more clear for those visiting?

Comment: For the record - I updated for use of `DateTime` - can't believe the accepted answer using used `DateTime` in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have just come across this in my code for a live app where the system incorrectly regarded today and tomorrow as today. We have just gone into British Summer Time and this has caused a problem with our app.

*I am now using the following, which is giving me the correct result:*

```
function days_away_to($dt) {
    $mkt_diff   = strtotime($dt) - time();
    return floor( $mkt_diff/60/60/24 ) + 1; # 0 = today, -1 = yesterday, 1 = tomorrow
}
```

Of course, using the DateTime class is the best solution going forward ...

Comment: This is exactly the same code that [was already posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8807610/447356) and you just changed the variable names. -1 for trying to get rep for other people's work and wasting our time.

Comment: Thanks SW but unfortunately that solution did not work for me: it is giving me 0 for 2014-03-31 telling me that that is the date for today (it is 30 March now in the UK). I have added +1, which corrects it for me.

Comment: So you should highlight this in your post by linking to that other answer and explaining that you just added 1 to make it work. Please make the edit and let me know.