# php work out time until a certain day

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have been trying to work out how to get the exact time to the second until a certain day and hour. I believe it is the `time` function in php but i cant seem to get my head around it.

I am trying to spit it out in the following format `'dd:hh:mm:ss'`

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this previous question that should help you along: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-xxx-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-xxx-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many days until XXX date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-xxx-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can use datediff for that http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php, and the following is how you use date to format it the way you want

http://php.net/date `echo date("d:H:i:s");`

EDIT:

if your php version doesn't permit, you could use:

```
function datediff($date) {
    return strtotime($date) - time();
}

echo datediff("2011-12-31 15:00");
```

Comment: Agree this is probably the best method but the only restriction being the PHP version installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('d:H:i:s', mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year));
```

Where `mktime()` returns a timestamp.