# Trying to calculate days to next birthday

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this script which calculates days until someone's next birthday (there's probably a better way of doing this) but anyway, if someone's birthday was 3 days ago I want it to give me 362 days until next birthday but it gives -3 instead. No problem, add 365 days to that to get correct answer but it simply doesn't work and I can't work out why...the code:

```
$resultcurdate = mysql_query("select curdate()",$db);

    $curdate = mysql_fetch_array($resultcurdate);

    $curdate1 = explode('-', $curdate[0]);
    $day1   = $curdate1[2];
    $month1 = $curdate1[1];
    $year1  = $curdate1[0];

    $birthdate = explode('-', $databack10[birthday]);
    $day   = $birthdate[2];
    $month = $birthdate[1];
    $year  = $birthdate[0];

    $year = $year1;

    if ($month1>$month){$year=$year+1;}

    $birthdate5 = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

    $resultdate = mysql_query("select datediff('$birthdate5', now())",$db);

    $databackdate = mysql_fetch_array($resultdate);

    if($databackdate < '0'){$databackdate = (365 + $databackdate); }
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Is there a way to do this with a SQL query? Birthday is date fieldtype.

Comment: You might be better of by using the `DateTime()` class?

Comment: Why are you doing that complexish operation with the dates before comparing them? What's wrong with `SELECT DATEDIFF( '$databack10[birthday]', NOW() )` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many days until XXX date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-xxx-date)

Comment: Why are you using MySQL to calculate the date? You already have the birthday and current date.

Comment: See my answer here using (reusable) SQL functions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966942/how-selecting-birthdays-7-days-before-today-in-mysql/20956363#20956363

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select 
date_field,
abs(if(right(curdate(),5) >= right(date_field,5),
datediff(curdate(),concat(year(curdate()+ interval 1 year),right(date_field,6))) ,
datediff(concat(year(curdate()),right(date_field,6)),curdate()))) as days
from table
```

Comment: searched for a few hours and then, finally, the very easy solution I was looking for.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate which has a bit less code:

`select
     365.25 -
        (
          TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '1974-02-28', CURDATE())
              mod 365.25
         ) AS days_till_birthday`

Explanation:
 1. Get the current age in days:
 `TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '1974-02-28', CURDATE())`
 2. Get how many days since the last birthday by dividing the current age in days by 365.25 and get the remainder:
`(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '1974-02-28', CURDATE()) mod 365.25)`
 3. Subtract the remainder from 365.25 to see how many days left until the birthday:
 `365.25 - (TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '1974-02-28', CURDATE()) mod 365.25)`