# how Selecting Birthdays 7 Days Before Today in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

i have date field and i query for selecting Birthday before 7 days in mysql.

for example 
if

> birth = 1986-08-05

if now is 2012-07-30 this query alarm me.
or

> birth = 1986-01-05

if now is 2012-12-30 this query alarm me.
birth is field of `user_table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find my select for this goal.

```
select *,birthdate,
concat(if(date_format(birthdate, '%m') = '12',date_format(curdate(), "%Y")
,date_format(now(), "%Y")),
date_format(date_add(curdate(), interval 7 day), '%Y')) as birthday 
from users 
HAVING birthday BETWEEN curdate() and date_add(curdate(), interval 7 day)
```

thanks from your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_table
where date_format(date_sub(birth, interval 7 days), "%m-%d")
    = date_format(now(), "%m-%d")
   or date_format(date_sub(birth, interval 7 days), "%m-%d") = '02-29'
  and month(now()) = 2 and month(date_add(now(), interval 1 day)) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL functions if you want reusable code and want to keep your SQL easy to read and maintain. A birthday is an anniversary, so...

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS anniversary_after;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION anniversary_after(anydate DATE, after DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE anniversary DATE;
  DECLARE years INTEGER;
  SET years = YEAR(after) - YEAR(anydate);
  SET anniversary = DATE_ADD(anydate, INTERVAL years YEAR);
  IF anniversary < after THEN
    SET anniversary = DATE_ADD(anniversary, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
  END IF;
  RETURN anniversary;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS anniversary;
CREATE FUNCTION anniversary(anydate DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
RETURN anniversary_after(anydate, CURRENT_DATE());
```

Show date of next anniversary:

```
SELECT anniversary('1994-04-05');
```

Show days until next anniversary:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(anniversary('1994-04-05'), CURRENT_DATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
SELECT user_name, DATE_SUB(birth, INTERVAL 7 DAYS) as SevenDaysBefore from user_table
```

Comment: thanks. but i want this query alarm to me when date was 7 days before Anniversary