# SQL Calculating day away from birthday using their DOB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have a question regarding finding birthdays according to the date they were born, sadly I haven't found an answer for this on this website.

I want the set a number foreach date that has X days away from being their birthday. Except i have a hard time using their DOB and datediff.

What I want:

```
John: 0 --Today his birthday
Eric:0
Ben:1 -- In this week
Jerry:1
Jules: 2 -- In this month
Tom: 3 -- all other dates
```

I have tried using `DATEDIFF` with format but the issue is that you can't use a format with `DATEDIFF`.

I tried without and this returned their birth dates.

This is the code I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [id],
         [fullname] = CONCAT(E.[name], 
                             (CASE 
                                  WHEN LEN(E.[preposition]) > 0 
                                      THEN ' ' + E.[preposition] 
                              END), 
                              ', ', E.[givenname]),
         [relationnumber],
         [day] = (CASE
                      WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [birthday], '2021-09-09') < 1 
                          THEN 0
                      WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [birthday], '2021-09-09') < 8 
                          THEN 1
                      WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [birthday], '2021-09-09') < 31 
                          THEN 2
                      ELSE 3
                  END),
         [birthday]
     FROM 
         [info].[member] E
     WHERE 
         [system_active] = 1) A
ORDER BY 
    day ASC
```

**Note**: the set date '2021-09-09' I get from URL

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
My (working) Solution

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [id]
        ,[fullname] = CONCAT(E.[name], (CASE WHEN LEN(E.[preposition])>0 THEN ' '+E.[preposition] END), ', ', E.[givenname])
        ,[relationnumber] 
        ,hi = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,[birthday], CAST('2021-09-09' as date)) , [birthday]) 
        ,[day] = 
        (
            CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(day, '2021-09-09', DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,[birthday], CAST('2021-09-09' as date)) , [birthday])) = 0 THEN 0
                WHEN DATEDIFF(day, '2021-09-09', DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,[birthday], CAST('2021-09-09' as date)) , [birthday])) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 1
                WHEN DATEDIFF(day, '2021-09-09', DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year,[birthday], CAST('2021-09-09' as date)) , [birthday])) BETWEEN 8 AND 31 THEN 2
                ELSE 3
            END
        )
        ,[birthday]
    FROM [info].[member] E
    WHERE [system_active] = 1
    ) A
    ORDER BY day ASC
```

For a better answer look at MatBailie's answer. This solution just worked for me

Comment: Your code assumes the `birthday` is 'this' year.  Do you already have a process that updates those dates each time they have a birthday?  *(So Fred might be born `1998-02-28`, but the `birthday` column would have `2022-02-28`?)*  If so, when does that `birthday` get updated?  *(At the beginning of the day of their birthday, at the end of the day of their birthday, at the end of the week of their birthday)*?  Or, is `birthday` actually a `date-of-birth` columns, where the `year` part would usually be quite far in the past?

Comment: Birthday is set at the day they were born , this column doesn't update

Comment: When you say `this week` and `this month`, ***exactly*** what do ***you*** mean? For `this week` you could mean "within in the next 7 days", or "within the previous 7 days", or that a 'working week' or 'calendar week' is considered to be Monday to Sunday inclusive, and you want to know if 'today' and the 'birthday' are in the same 'working week'....

Comment: Within the next x days , for a week:  today is the 9th. I would like everey person that has their birthday from the 9th to the 15th.

Comment: That's more than a week, that's 8 days. And what does "month" mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to calculate days to next birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377559/trying-to-calculate-days-to-next-birthday)

Comment: @Stu That's only half an answer to the specific question, particularly when dealing with "within the next month", because a month can be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days.  *(It's useful, helpful, but doesn't complete the OP's needs.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the features of `DATEDIFF()` is that a difference of 0 means that the values are in the same day/week/month/year.

This means that any date last year is always 1 year away from any other date in this year.

- `DATEDIFF(year, '2020-01-01', '2021-09-09') == 1`
- `DATEDIFF(year, '2020-12-31', '2021-09-09') == 1`

It's not counting whole years between dates.  It's counting the difference of the year part only.

---

What this means is that I follow the following process...

Work out their next birthday...

- Work out the person's birthday this year
- If that was before today's date, add one more year
- Which give's their next birthday (treating a birthday today as their next birthday)

Compare that to fixed date...

- Is their next birthday today?
- Is their next birthday before today+7days?
- Is their next birthday before today+1month?

I do that as follows...  *(Amended to make it easier to parameterise the date this is all being calculated relative to)*

```
SELECT
  member.*,
  next.birthday   AS next_birthday,
  CASE WHEN next.birthday  =                   today.date  THEN 0
       WHEN next.birthday <= DATEADD(DAY,   7, today.date) THEN 1
       WHEN next.birthday <= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, today.date) THEN 2
                                                                        ELSE 3
  END
      AS next_birthday_type
FROM
  member
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CAST('2021-09-09' AS DATE)
)
  today(date)
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, member.birthday, today.date), member.birthday)
)
  AS this_year(birthday)
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN this_year.birthday < today.date
              THEN DATEADD(year, 1, this_year.birthday)
              ELSE                  this_year.birthday
          END
)
  AS next(birthday)
```

Demos : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df444333bab146d4d923b210e813e852