# How do I find how many days are within a date range that are within another date range in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date-range, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon PHP library.The answer in the duplicate question uses PHP's built in function.

[count how many days within a date range are within another date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227912/count-how-many-days-within-a-date-range-are-within-another-date-range)

---

Below is the code that I use to find if a date range(`$userDateStart` and `$userDateEnd`) is with in another date range (`$couponStart and`$couponEnd`) and it works fine without any error but I don't know how to find the days that overlap/exists that is in this date range?

The library I'm using is http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

The expected result should be 4 in this case..Hope you will help me.

```
$userDateStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-26');
$userDateEnd  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-29');

$couponStart  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-26');
$couponEnd    = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-10-31');

if(($userDateStart >= $couponStart && $userDateEnd <= $couponEnd) ||
    ($couponStart >= $userDateStart && $couponEnd <= $userDateEnd)){
    die("Yes,The date is within this date range");
}
die("No,It is not within this date range");
```

Comment: The difficulty you have in understanding the answer to the previous question has no bearing whether the question is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm using Carbon PHP library.Surely there is some other easy way to calculate the days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count how many days within a date range are within another date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227912/count-how-many-days-within-a-date-range-are-within-another-date-range)

Comment: @rogerduce He just stated it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm using Carbon PHP library and I don't want to use built in PHP interval class like that answer in duplicate quesiton.

Comment: @JayBlanchard So the difference between a Library he is using vs PHP's built in functions.... I'd say there is no duplication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245776/using-carbon-to-know-if-a-time-falls-under-two-points-of-time-or-not

Comment: have you read my question ?  @JayBlanchard I want to find how many days are within a date range that are within another date range and it is  not as simple as the question you posted.

Comment: Yes, I have read your question. Please do not ask me things like that when I am trying to be helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry if you find my comment rude.

Comment: no.I there is no need for a DB here.

Comment: That link I posted explains very clearly how to use `between()` to determine if an instance is between any two instances. It's [right here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Documentation that was provided, You need to use this:

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 4, 30, 0);
echo $dt->diffInDays($dt->copy()->addMonth()); // 30
echo $dt->diffInDays($dt->copy()->addWeek()); // 7
```

So to work with your program I'm thinking you'll need to do this:

```
$userDateStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-26');
$userDateEnd  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-29');

$couponStart  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-06-26');
$couponEnd    = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2015-10-31');

//Determin the highest date from the starts and the minimum dates from the ends
$startBetweenDate = $userDateStart->max($couponStart);
$endBetweenDate = $userDateEnd->min($couponEnd);

//Now find how many days are between
echo $startBetweenDate->diffInDays($endBetweenDate); //Should be 4
```

Please note: This was not tested as I do not have Carbon's library installed.

Comment: thanks for this solution but It doesn't work on some rare cases.