# How many days left till any date?

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many days until XXX date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-xxx-date)

Currently I am using this code to determine how many days left till an expected day. But this code shows unexpected result. For example if $last_date is 26 December 2012, then I will get `0 day(s) left.` But it should be `1 day(s) left.` I think my problem is only with `floor()` function. Isn't it?

```
 $timezone = "Asia/Dhaka";
 if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

 $now = time();
 $last_date = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
 $datediff = $last_date - $now;
 $day_left=floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
 echo "$day_left day(s) left.";
```

N:B: My timezone is +6 GMT, I mean Asia/Dhaka.

Comment: There are some similar questions. As I want to edit my own code, I posted my question here. Thanks.

Comment: @rambocoder that is an old post using a now archaic method of determing the days. We now have DateTime() using the diff() method to achieve it using a modern approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
<?php

$year = '2012';
$month = '12';
$day = '26';

$current_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
$end_date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
$interval = $current_date->diff($end_date);
echo $interval->format('%a day(s)');

?>
```

Comment: I printed your code, but it showed +6015 days, I think it should be 2 days.

Comment: @user1902462 prints 2 days for me. See edited code, I had previously posted the PHP.net example verbatim. Btw you would need to edit it to input your variables.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. But it couldn't work in my localhost. It says 6015 day for every time I tried. :(

Anyway I accepted your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1902462 did you copy the most current post exactly? I did it so all you have to do is basically copy and paste (remove the temp $year, $month and $day vars of course)

Comment: Yes I did and in a whole new page. But it is 6015 day(s).

Comment: @user1902462 What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21661/discussion-between-cryptic-and-user1902462)

Comment: How do you display the word "day" if $interval is only 1?  I've tried the following:  if ($interval > '1') {
echo $interval->format('%a days');
} else {
echo $interval->format('%a day');
}   but this still displays "days" even when 1 is displayed.

Comment: @NathonJones `$interval` is not a string, it's an object. So do this:

`$days = $interval->format('%a');

echo "$days day";
if ('1' !== $days) {
    echo 's';
}`

This will output '# day' and apply an 's' if it does not equal '1'. This also accounts for '0', as you say '0 days' not '0 day'.