# Translate date value into how many days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i get a date from a service like "2020-01-08 09:48:34" But how can i transform this with jQuery into "1 day to go" or when the date is "2020-01-15 11:24:34" into "8 days to go"?

I know there are scripts like: [How many days until X-Y-Z date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654363/how-many-days-until-x-y-z-date) but i am stuck on this date format what i showed above.

Comment: You can't do this with jQuery. You need JavaScript and/or a different library like Moment.js

Comment: @vlaz how is this possible with only JS? thats fine also by me but i cant use a differtent libary for this.

Comment: `new Date('2020-01-08 09:48:34')` then see the duplicate I marked

Comment: JavaScript does the date manipulation, while jQuery doesn't have any date functionality aside from `$.now()` which is just a thin wrapper for `(new Date).getTime()`.

Comment: [How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836) This is for the past ( eg: *"1 days ago"*). You need to implement similarly for the future

Comment: The safest format to use is actually the abbreviated/simplified ISO8601 format, where the date and time are separated by `T`, even though JS can parse the date propery. This is recommended: `new Date('2020-01-08T09:48:34')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it by getting `date` difference.

Here, `selected_date` is your date.

Ideally, you should only use `date` part for getting your result.

```js
var cur_date = "2020-01-08 12:23:12"
var selected_date = "2020-01-01 10:23:33"
var cur_date_date_part = new Date(cur_date).getFullYear()+ '-'+(new Date(cur_date).getMonth()+1)+'-'+new Date(cur_date).getDate()

var selected_date_date_part = new Date(selected_date).getFullYear()+ '-'+(new Date(selected_date).getMonth()+1)+'-'+new Date(selected_date).getDate()

var resultDays = ((Date.parse(cur_date_date_part) - Date.parse(selected_date_date_part)) / 86400000)
if (resultDays > 0){
  console.log(Math.abs(resultDays) + " days ago")
  }
else{
  console.log(Math.abs(resultDays) + " days to go")
  }
```

Comment: This seems to work! And how can i make the value smaller? Like now i get: "0.8548958333333333 days to go" how to translate that to "1 day to go" so i only get full days and not behind the comma. (i have the hours, minutes and seconds also in the date) :-)

Comment: @Maanstraat use `Math.ceil()`

Comment: As said by @Maanstraat, either you can use `Math.ceil()` or you can just take date part and calculate as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: As mentioned by @VLAZ, you can use Moment.js library which will give you more flexibility with dates.

Comment: `new Date(‘2020-01-08 12:23:12’)` returns an invalid Date in at least one current implementation, the method of reduction to the date component is grossly over complicated, jQuery is included for no reason, there is no explanation of how it works.